# How do i make a piezo play 3 times and then stopping in Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino

EDIT: https://www.tinkercad.com/things/ampvgOj75D1
This is the link to my tinkercad project witch contains the wiring of the circuit, sorry that i forgot it's also needed to get the code working.

I need this code to make the piezo play 3 times and then stopping it completely, the `while()` loop does not work for some reason.
I tried moving around the `i++` function but it does not work. If i state `i=0;` globally the piezo never plays, if i put it in `loop()` it keeps repeating without stopping the third time.

```
int i=0;
const byte speakerPin=9;
unsigned long CurrentMillis;
unsigned long lastPeriodStart;
const int onDuration=100;
const int periodDuration=500;


void setup()
{
pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop()
{
  CurrentMillis = millis();
  Serial.println(i);
  

  while(i<=3) 
{
  
    
  if (CurrentMillis-lastPeriodStart>=periodDuration)
  {
    lastPeriodStart = millis();
    tone(speakerPin,550, onDuration); 
    
  }
  i++;
    
}
  
  
  
}
```

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual code not work due to variable `i` is incremented in every loop. So this mean `i` is more then 3 in very short time and `if` statement is still false.
If you move `i++` statement inside `if`, your code not leave `while` loop, because `CurrentMillis` is not updated.
My recomendation:

1. use `Serial.println("message");` to trace your code, in all branches your code
2. move `i++;` statement inside `if`
3. replace `while` statement by `if`